# SAS how to create a macro program procsurveyselect

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I need to do a random simple sampling withouth replacement of 50k  on a df of 500k data.

So I have this dataframe located in lib_d1.df

| Var A | Var B || Var C | Var D || Var E | Var F || Var G | Var H |

I want to create a macro program data_sample(list_var,nb_obs,table_name)

```
%macro data_sample(list_var, nb_obs, table_name)
data_null_ nobs= n;       
Set lib_d1.df;
call symput("nb_obs", n);
run;

    
proc surveyselect seed=30602 data=&list_var n=&nb_obs out=&table_name;
run;         
%mend        
%let list_var= Var A, Var D, Var E, Var H;
&let nb_obs= &nb_obs;
%let table_name= data_50000;
%data_sample(list_var,nb_obs,table_name);
```

yeah that's where I'm at, and i have no clue what is right (or what is wrong...any help would be appreciated)

Comment: Please also make sure to mark you questions as solved, when they're resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you might want to consider renaming all your variable's names to comply with [SAS naming conventions](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=acreldb&docsetTarget=p036tss31xui33n1qh7s4aeyb0uz.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en). I would not recommend to play around with variables that have a space in their names. However, if you want to keep your data set as it is right now, try the following:

```
%macro data_sample(input=,list_var=,obs=,output=);
proc surveyselect seed=30602 
                  data=&input.(keep= &list_var.)
                  n=&obs. 
                  out=&output.;
run;         
%mend;
   
%data_sample(input=have,
            list_var='Var A'n 'Var D'n 'Var E'n 'Var H'n,
            obs=50000,
            output=want);
```

`method=srs` is simple random sampling, which is selection with equal probability and without replacement. Find more information in the [PROC SURVEYSELECT](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.4&docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_surveyselect_syntax01.htm&locale=en#statug.surveyselect.selectmethod) documentation. By default, this is set to SRS but always good to know.

By the way, I don't think the first data step you made would run because `nobs=n` has to be placed after the set statement. Also, I don't know why you are computing the number of observations in your data set if you are only interested in a fixed sample of 50 000 observations.

I would suggest to consider using the following if you want to compute a macro-variable (in that case `nbobs`) with the number of observations in your data set:

```
data _null_;
if 0 then set lib_d1.df nobs=n;
call symputx('nbobs',n);
stop;
run;
```